# Unity Take and Throw Ball

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rigid-bodies

I'm try to make Basketball hoops, I can throw ball one time, I reset game but I can not throw ball again , I don't like to reset scene.

`GameController` is a empty object [**Manager**] and below script attach to it.

**GameController.cs:**

```cs
    public PlayerArcade player;
    public float restartTime = 5f;
    public static bool ResetBall = false;

    void Start()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
  
    void Update()
    {
        if(player.HoldingBall == false)
        {
            restartTime -= Time.deltaTime;
            if (restartTime <= 0)
            {
                //SceneManager.LoadScene("Intro");
                ResetBall = true;
                restartTime = 5f;
            }              
               // ResetBall = true;
        }        
    }
```

My main player script as **PlayerArcade.cs:**

```cs
    public GameObject Ball;
    public Ball ball;
    Rigidbody ballrb;
    public GameObject PlayerCamera;
    public float BallDistance = 1f;
    public float ThrowPowerStrong = 550f;
    public float ThrowPowerWeak = 350f;
    public bool HoldingBall = true;

    void Start()
    {
        ballrb = Ball.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
        ballrb.useGravity = false;
    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
    void Update()
    {
        if (GameController.ResetBall == true)
        {
            ballrb.constraints = RigidbodyConstraints.None;
            Ball.transform.position = new Vector3(212.5f, 3.227f, 4.11f);
            ballrb.velocity = Vector3.zero;
            ballrb.angularVelocity = Vector3.zero;
            ballrb.transform.eulerAngles = new Vector3(0f, 0f, 0f);
            ballrb.useGravity = false;
            HoldingBall = true;
        }
        if (HoldingBall)
                {
                    Ball.transform.position = PlayerCamera.transform.position + PlayerCamera.transform.forward * BallDistance;

            if (Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Y))
                {
                Debug.Log(ThrowPowerStrong);
                HoldingBall = false;
                ballrb.useGravity = true;
                ballrb.AddForce(PlayerCamera.transform.forward * ThrowPowerStrong);
            }

            if (Input.GetKeyUp(KeyCode.A))
                {
                 HoldingBall = false;
                 ballrb.useGravity = true;
                 ballrb.AddForce(PlayerCamera.transform.forward * ThrowPowerWeak);
                 }
                }
    }
```

And **Ball.cs** is attached to my ball object:

```cs
    public PlayerArcade player;
    [SerializeField] Transform PlayerBall;
    Rigidbody ballrb;

    // Start is called before the first frame update
    void Start()
    {
        ballrb = PlayerBall.GetComponent<Rigidbody>();
    }
    private void Awake()
    {
        Cursor.lockState = CursorLockMode.Locked;
        Cursor.visible = false;
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

when you throw the ball by pressing (A, or Y) just do
GameController.ResetBall = false; `GameController.ResetBall = false;`